# Histogram of Array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, histogram

I'm trying to write a generic histogram function that operates on an `Array`, but I'm running into difficulties as **Type 'Element' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'**.

```
extension Array {
    func histogram() -> [Array.Element: Int] {
        return self.reduce([Array.Element: Int]()) { (acc, key) in
                let value = (acc[key] == nil) ? 1 : (acc[key]! + 1)
                return acc.dictionaryByUpdatingKey(key: key, value: value)
        }
    }
}
```

where `dictionaryByUpdatingKey(...)` mutates an existing dictionary as follows:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func dictionaryByUpdatingKey(key: Dictionary.Key, value: Dictionary.Value) -> Dictionary {
        var mutableSelf = self
        let _ = mutableSelf.updateValue(value, forKey: key)
        return mutableSelf
    }
}
```

I have tried replacing `Array.Element` with `AnyHashable` and then forcing the `key as! AnyHashable`, but this seems messy and the return type should preferably be of the same type as the `Array.Element` and not of `AnyHashable`.

I wish to use the `Array` extension as follows:

```
let names = ["Alex", "Alex", "James"]
print(names.histogram()) // ["James": 1, "Alex": 2]
```

or

```
let numbers = [2.0, 2.0, 3.0]
print(numbers.histogram()) // [3.0: 1, 2.0: 2]
```

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46997085/4601900

Comment: You should learn about `reduce(into:updateAccumulatingResult:)` which is more efficient in such cases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the *generic where clause*: `where Element: Hashable` to your extension:

```
extension Sequence where Element: Hashable {
    func histogram() -> [Element: Int] {
        return self.reduce([Element: Int]()) { (acc, key) in
            let value = acc[key, default: 0] + 1
            return acc.dictionaryByUpdatingKey(key: key, value: value)
        }
    }
}
```

I also incorporated @MartinR's suggestion of using the new `default` value for dictionary look ups.

---

Using [`reduce(into:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2924692-reduce) you can do this much more simply and efficiently:

```
extension Sequence where Element: Hashable {
    func histogram() -> [Element: Int] {
        return self.reduce(into: [:]) { counts, elem in counts[elem, default: 0] += 1 }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great.

Comment: Simpler: `let value = acc[key, default: 0] + 1`

Comment: Have a look at your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30545629/1187415 :)

Comment: LOL, I know @MartinR.  I was focused on the question at hand this time and didn't look at the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

First, you could limit the Element type to only be Hashable.

```
extension Array where Array.Element:Hashable {
```

After this, you might get another error because the swift compiler is a little "overstrained". Try to give him a hint:

```
typealias RT = [Array.Element: Int]
```

and use it everywhere. So:

```
extension Array where Array.Element:Hashable {
    typealias RT = [Array.Element: Int]
    func histogram() -> RT {
        return self.reduce(RT()) { (acc, key) in
            let value = (acc[key] == nil) ? 1 : (acc[key]! + 1)
            return acc.dictionaryByUpdatingKey(key: key, value: value)
        }
    }
}
```

finally should work.