# How to find duplicate and show the count in table view

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, uitextfield

I have an list of array like and I needs to show in table view

```
let data = ["a", "a", "b", "c"]
```

In my table view, I need to show all the string in each row. That i done.But i need to find the duplicate and needs to update the count like say. In my array i have `a` as `2 counts`.

So in my table view I needs to show like

```
a(2)
b
c
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545518/how-to-count-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-swift-array

Comment: page not found error is coming

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46996966/swift-4-how-to-return-a-count-of-duplicate-values-from-an-array

Comment: Kindly Check now

Comment: i tried that earlier, but i am using tabke view.not sure how can i populate that data as array string in to my table view..please help m eon that

Comment: Add code for how you are populating data.

Comment: make your values into Dictonary, They state that clearly

Comment: but i was not able to show that in to my table view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class TableVC: UIViewController {

    //MARK: - Outlet & Properties
    let data = ["a", "a", "b", "c"]
    var unique = [String]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.dataSource = self
        unique = Array(Set(data)) // Here you will get Unique Elements of Array
    }

}

//MARK: - UITableView datasource
extension TableVC : UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return unique.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! tableCell
        cell.label.text = unique[indexPath.row] + " " +  String(data.filter{$0 == unique[indexPath.row]}.count)

        print(data.filter{$0 == unique[indexPath.row]}.count) // Here you will get COUNT of an Element.
        return cell
    }
}
```